# Can any one tell me what is wrong with this query

Tags: php, postgresql

I have this query with parameters prom http `$_POST` and its not working . can any one tell me what is wrong with it.

```
  if ($category != 'All' && $status !='All' && $name !='All'){
                 $query = "SELECT " .$select." FROM afro_fixed_asset  WHERE fixed_asset_category = '".$category."'AND fixed_asset_status= '".$status."' AND fixed_asset_acquisition_date BETWEEN '".$acquisition_from."' AND '".$acquisition_to."'"."' AND fixed_asset_registered_date BETWEEN '".$registration_from."' AND '".$registration_to."'";
                }
```

Error Says

```
SELECT fixed_asset_id,fixed_asset_name,fixed_asset_category,fixed_asset_status FROM afro_fixed_asset WHERE fixed_asset_status = 'Operational (In use)' AND fixed_asset_category= 'Computer & Computer Accessory'AND fixed_asset_name= 'Bur Cutter' AND fixed_asset_acquisition_date BETWEEN '03/26/2017' AND '03/27/2017'' AND fixed_asset_registered_date BETWEEN '04/12/2017'' AND '04/03/2017'

Status 7 - ERROR: syntax error at or near "04" LINE 1: ...7/2017'' AND fixed_asset_registered_date BETWEEN '04/12/2017... ^
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would that result in a syntax error?

Comment: No Bro. It works fine with other queries with same date format except this one. Problem is syntax and I could nt figure it out.

Comment: @BartFriederichs No, it might not cause a syntax error, but only a logical one in that the `BETWEEN` clause won't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I clearly says he has a syntax error, so your remark about the dates is not the issue he is having now. Postgres is choking on the extra quote (') he has in his query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct query

```
$query = "SELECT " .$select." FROM afro_fixed_asset  WHERE fixed_asset_status = '".$status."' AND fixed_asset_category= '".$category."' AND fixed_asset_name= '".$name."' AND fixed_asset_acquisition_date BETWEEN '".$acquisition_from."' AND '".$acquisition_to."' AND fixed_asset_registered_date BETWEEN '".$registration_from."' AND '".$registration_to."'";
```

Comment: Thanx Man. Just like I like it.

Answer (score 0):

**First and foremost, use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). That will fix this issue.**

Second, your problem is here:

```
... AND '".$acquisition_to."'"."' ...
```

You add two `'` characters, edit to show like this:

```
... AND '".$acquisition_to."' ...
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen perhaps, but that is not the question.

Comment: Then why did you suggest prepared statements, since that is also not the direct question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 1, the date format is accepted: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE, 2 using prepared statements would help in a better way as it would show the error more readily, 3 I do address the actual issue at hand

Comment: You're right, Postgres will accept this date format, I never knew this :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is pretty easy, you have one `'` too much in your query near the end:

```
SELECT fixed_asset_id,fixed_asset_name,fixed_asset_category,fixed_asset_status 
FROM afro_fixed_asset 
WHERE fixed_asset_status = 'Operational (In use)' 
AND fixed_asset_category= 'Computer & Computer Accessory' 
AND fixed_asset_name= 'Bur Cutter' 
AND fixed_asset_acquisition_date BETWEEN '03/26/2017' 
AND '03/27/2017'' // Error here, one ' too much
AND fixed_asset_registered_date BETWEEN '04/12/2017'' AND '04/03/2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra sigle quote `'".$registration_from."'"."' AND "` before AND u can see `"'"` and you already concate single quote with `$registration_from`. if you remove that your query will work fine.